# How to customize sum function of tree view in Odoo?

Tags: xml, sum, treeview, odoo, odoo-10

I have a treeview which list out Expenses and Revenues records. And there is a column of amount which is applied with SUM function in xml. My requirement is to make all amounts in -ve where type=Revenues in treeview so that when it gets sumed up the result will be Expenses minus Revenues. Below is my treeview please help. Thanks in advance!

```
<record id="view_program_activity_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">program.activity.tree</field>
    <field name="model">program.activity</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <tree string="Program Activity" colors="green:type_id[1] == 'REVENUE'">

            <field name="department_id"/>
            <field name="sector_id"/>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="code"/>
            <field name="type_id"/>
            <field name="total_planned" sum="Total Planned"/>

        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific and clear.

Comment: If you can see I have a field total_planned, that is the amount field and it gives sum of the total_planned column. And there is one more field type_id which has contains text either Expenses or Revenues. I need where ever type_id is Revenue the total_planned figure to be converted to negative sign. Now since the total_planned field has SUM function it will calculate all Expenses as positive and all Revenues as negative values. Overall I need to achieve Expenses minus Revenues result in the bottom of the tree under total_planned column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a new computed field `total_planned_signed` which depends on `total_planned` and `type_id`, and just show this new field in your list view:

```py
total_planned_signed = fields.Float(
    string="Total Planned", compute="_compute_total_planned_signed",
    store=True)

@api.depends('total_planned', 'type_id')
def _compute_total_planned_signed(self):
    for activity in self:
        if activity.type_id.name == 'REVENUE':
            activity.total_planned_signed = activity.total_planned
        else:
            activity.total_planned_signed = -activity.total_planned
```

And now just substitute `total_planned` in your list view with `total_planned_signed`.

Or if it's possible, just always compute or set `total_planned` as signed value.